# jQuery for Tumblr?

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I'm developing my first Tumblr-theme. Is it possible to just include jQuery from Google Code and then use it?

Also, is there any good jQuery-script for showing latest tweet in Twitter? I've read Tumblrs own javascript-method, but if jQuery works, I'm gonna use that of course.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate twitter you can use this plugin:
http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

Or build your own script using Twitter Json(p) api:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html